# PassportJS not redirecting after user is authenticated

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, passport.js

I have the following code for processing the `signin` request using PassportJS to authenticate/authorize user:

```
app.post('/signin', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.json(info);
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            res.redirect('/user'); //not redirecting to /user
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

But it is not redirecting to `/user` once the user is found.

Could somebody help me understand why is it not redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you throw a console.log statement above your redirect line? Is that code being executed? It looks to me as if your code is never getting to the redirect call.

Comment: It gets logged alright on the console when I do that before the redirect line. I've been doing the redirect for now from the front end by sending a json response from the function above.

Comment: Are you using angular or something like that? Or are you using server-side views? If you're using angular or whatnot and you have another piece of code intercepting your request then the request won't go through because you have to read it in your front-end code and do the redirect there.

Comment: @rdeggs: I send a post request using `$http` service from an `ejs` using AngularJS. I am doing it like this `app.post('/signin', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {  return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.json(info); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            res.json({user: user});
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});` and then doing the redirect from an AngularJS controller.

Comment: Ah, that's why it is failing then. YOU MUST return JSON from your express-endpoint, then look at the response from angular, and then redirect if that response tells you to. The express res.redirect() has no effect unless it's getting to the user's browser directly -- the angular stuff is preventing it from doing it's work.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that exactly? I am not sure if I am able to see things clearly. Does `res.redirect("/users")` does not redirect when we ask it too?

Comment: When you say res.redirect('/users'); -- what happens is that express returns an HTTP 302 redirect to the caller -- in this case your Angular script. This means that your angular code must READ in that request and do something with it since the user's browser isn't receiving that request directly.